# How might one stop a radioactive agent from radiating?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity, half-life

[Source](https://news.yahoo.com/russian-citizens-now-being-prepped-164259149.html)

> There have also been grim signs of things to come from the Russian government. A new national standard for “Urgent burial of corpses in peacetime and wartime” has been introduced by the government in recent months. It will come into force on Feb. 1, 2022, and specifies the burial in mass graves to be dug by bulldozers, disposing of as many as 1,000 bodies in a 24-hour time period. Bodies are to be placed “in four layers, either in bags, wooden coffins or zinc coffins, prepared in advance… and subsequently covered with dirt. Then the mass graves will be compacted with a bulldozer, filled with “a mineral binder” and **equipped with “devices for the absorption and neutralization of radioactive, hazardous chemicals and biological agents formed during the decomposition of corpses.**”

I can see how a device might neutralize biological agents - a powerful poison ought to do it. I can also see how one might neutralize hazardous chemicals: some chemical reaction can turn the chemical no longer dangerous, e.g. sulfuric acid can be neutralized with a base. I don't, however, see how any device might stop radioactivity. After all, the half life of radioactive nuclei is usually constant. The best one can do is build a shield around the radioactive materials, but this doesn't sound like what the article is talking about.

How might such a device work?

Comment: If you knew that the bodies were contaminated with a specific radioactive chemical, you might design some barrier layer that would react with that chemical to _immobilize_ the radionuclide. You could not render it non-radioactive, but at least you might prevent it from leaching into the soil and the groundwater.

Comment: @SolomonSlow sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

from your source

"for the absorption and neutralization of radioactive, "

covers a lot, and as Solomon says one should know what the source of radiation is.

[This is the maximum protection  :](https://www.britannica.com/science/radioactivity)

> An operating reactor is a powerful source of radiation, since fission and subsequent radioactive decay produce neutrons and gamma rays, both of which are highly penetrating radiations. A reactor must have specifically designed shielding around it to absorb and reflect this radiation in order to protect technicians and other reactor personnel from exposure.

But there exist a lot of firms creating radiation protection for specific needs ,if one searches "shields for radioactivity".